# Проблема с форматированием в профиле

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, дизайн

Отображение блока активности в профиле не совсем корректно отформатировано:

[image: Текст вылезает за границы блока]

Текст вылезает за границы блока.

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/276/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy fixed :)